# Структура IPV6 (Winsock)

Tags: winsock, c++

Хотел добавить поддержку IPV6 в приложение,но не знаю в какой *.h файле хранятся структуры sockaddr_in6. Visual studio постоянно ругается на то что не может найти sockaddr_in6 структур

Answer (score 3):

У меня (в MinGW Windows) в ws2tcpip.h